# Slow query and returning times before current time

Tags: php, mysql

My site is loading very slowly, it's only a single page that is loading slow, and I suspect it is because of a MySQL query being sent to the database. How can I speed it up?

```
$depquery = "SELECT * FROM phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE'
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)>0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY deptime ASC";
```

The query is basically working to extract information into a 'Departure Board' table. The table is sorted by `deptime`, and it displays results from current time onwards. However, I also want it to go back at least 4 records, to 4 flights before current time.

To clarify, let me give you an example:

It's now 15:25. Because of `if(($flight->deptime) >= $time)` and `if($count < 15)` and inside a `foreach` it will display 15 records on and after that time. However, I want to also travel back 4 records, so it finds last 4 records before 15:25. Is this possible?

Basically, I want to search up and down around the current time.

Comment: are the fields on the WHERE statement indexed? even if they are it's much better if you could precalculate the values related to the time instead of asking mysql to do the conversion. IIRC some time conversions will make the query to use the field as it was not indexed at all.

Comment: Apologies for this silly question. How do you check whether it's indexed?

Comment: try `SHOW INDEX FROM phpvms_schedules`

Comment: @Naryl: http://i.imgur.com/qdKjyRC.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You want a UNION, something like:

```
SELECT * phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE' 
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,
     ".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)>0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY deptime ASC
LIMIT 15
UNION ALL
SELECT * phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE' 
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,
     ".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)<0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY deptime DESC
LIMIT 4
```

Note I didn't guess on your date function because I don't know what it is doing. I just changed the > to a < and the ordering on deptime to DESC. (One of those < > might need to also have an = to not miss a departure right now?)

Using the LIMIT will do the filtering in the DB as opposed to in code which it sounds like you are doing. This will reduce the overhead of processing this information in code and should make it much quicker. I would also sort the UNION of these results in the DB and avoid doing it in code.

**EDIT**

Just to be completely clear this should handle the sorting in the DB:

```
SELECT tbl* FROM (
SELECT * phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE' 
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,
     ".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)>0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY deptime ASC
LIMIT 15
UNION ALL
SELECT * phpvms_schedules 
WHERE code = 'FE' 
AND locate(dayofweek(convert_tz(now(),'+1:00','+0:00'))-1,
     ".TABLE_PREFIX."schedules.daysofweek)<0
AND phpvms_schedules.enabled = '1'
ORDER BY deptime DESC
LIMIT 4
) as tbl ORDER BY tbl.deptime ASC
```

Comment: How is `UNION` used? I'm slightly confused because it's throwing a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` if I throw this entire code into `$depquery`. I guess I've missed something?

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with my copying the locate code without understanding it - you may have to tweak that part. The UNION should be good.

Comment: There's a quote after `ORDER BY deptime ASC"` AND `ORDER BY deptime DESC"`.

Comment: Note that the records aren't in the correct order with this `UNION` query. Causing you to have to do the sorting in PHP. It's easier just to do 2 queries and combine the results. Also using a varchar field for `dayofweek` slows things down significantly (see my answer).

Comment: Edited: One sec, only noticed the above answer, just going to do this in two queries...

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels I noted that in my last sentence - I would wrap the whole thing in a SELECT * (...) Order by deptime

Comment: @zzwyb89 Would still do this in one query - for the volume we are talking about efficiency is not going to be an issue, but it is always good practice to let the DB do what it does well :)